# Django CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-urls, cors

Estoy intentando redirigir una función View de Django a una página en PHP, de momento alojada en mi propio equipo.

El caso es que he visto que me da un error de cruce de dominios por culpa de estar llamando a otro enlace de mi propio equipo.

He encontrado un modulo llamado django-cors-headers y lo he configurado tal y como viene en la documentación https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers

```
    MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = False
```

Después al final de la función le paso la url pero me sigue dando el mismo error

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('http://localhost/pruebas/prueba.php',{'datos':datos})
```

y esta es la respuesta:

```
Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen
impide leer el recurso remoto en http://localhost/pruebas/prueba.php
(razón: falta la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin').
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo estás haciendo al revés, CORS funciona así:

1. Tienes el servidor A, desde donde cargas en tu navegador una página con JS.
2. Dicho JS intenta acceder mediante AJAX al servidor B.

En este escenario es B quien tiene que implementar CORS para explícitamente aceptar llamadas desde el código del servidor A.

Comment: ahora lo entiendo... es que era la única "solución" que habia visto. muchas gracias

Comment: ahora me surje otro problema, he activado el uso de cors en el apache de PHP pero ahora me devuelve este mensaje: Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen impide leer el recurso remoto en http://localhost/pagos/pago.php (razón: token 'x-csrftoken' no presente en la cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' del canal CORS prevuelo).

Comment: Parece que además de CORS tienes protección contra CSRF: tienes que mandar ese token al servidor B, por lo tanto B tiene explícitamente que aceptar ese header